# How to make canvas in javascript show a custom image as a background?

Tags: javascript, background, html5-canvas

I'm having problems with placing a custom image (dirt.png) on a canvas as it's background, so that it's elements on it would not be behind. Really hard to explain the problem, because it's really hard for me to understand the code. This is the beginner stuff, hope you guys will get it. Thanx!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ussi l6una</title>
    <script>
      var kohad=new Array();
      var pikkus=1, d=6, kogus=300;

      tahvel {
  background-image:url(dirt.png);
  }

      function looKohad(){
         for(var i=0; i<kogus; i++){
            kohad[i]=new Array(pikkus*i, 1200);
         }
      }

      function arvutaUusTagumine(eesmine, tagumine){
         var kaugus=new Array();
         kaugus[0]=eesmine[0]-tagumine[0];
         kaugus[1]=eesmine[1]-tagumine[1];
         var kogukaugus=Math.sqrt(kaugus[0]*kaugus[0]+kaugus[1]*kaugus[1]);
         var nihe=kogukaugus-pikkus;
         var dx=kaugus[0]*nihe/kogukaugus;
         var dy=kaugus[1]*nihe/kogukaugus;  
         return new Array(tagumine[0]+dx, tagumine[1]+dy);       
      }

      function arvutaUuedKohad(){
         console.log(kohad);
         for(var i=1; i<kogus; i++){
            kohad[i]=arvutaUusTagumine(kohad[i-1], kohad[i]);
         }
      }

      function joonistaKohad(g){
         for(var i=0; i<kogus; i++){
            joonistaKoht(g, kohad[i])
         }
      }

      function joonistaKoht(g, koht){
         g.beginPath();
         g.arc(koht[0], koht[1], d, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);
         g.stroke();      
      }

      function hiirLiigub(e){
         var t=document.getElementById("tahvel");
         var g=t.getContext("2d");
         var tahvlikoht=t.getBoundingClientRect();
         kohad[0][0]=e.clientX-tahvlikoht.left;
         kohad[0][1]=e.clientY-tahvlikoht.top;
         arvutaUuedKohad();
         g.strokeStyle="#fff";
         g.fillStyle="blue";
         g.clearRect(0, 0, t.width, t.height);
         joonistaKohad(g);
      }
      looKohad();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="tahvel" width="800" height="800" 
       style="background-color: #505050" onmousemove="hiirLiigub(event)"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please describe what your code is supposed to be doing and what it does instead? Also, you seem to be missing some code. For example, do you make sure the image is loaded before you use it for drawing?

Comment: here, i just want to put a custom background for my canvas but  can't figure out how; sorry for non english code

Answer (score 0):

When you have a static background, then why not let the browsers rendering engine do the work for you?

Instead of setting the background-color in the style of the `<canvas>` tag, set a `background-image:url(yourbackgroundimage.png)`.